# imacros function iimPlay() lose previously established proxy connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, proxy, imacros

This script picks a random proxy from a list, then goes to a website to confirm the proxy is able to access to the internet. If the website is successfully loaded, then continue by loading another .iim file

The problem is that the proxy connection is lost when executing iimPlay() here:

```
iimPlay(part2);  // at this point the proxy connection is established
iimPlay("C:\Users\Libertad\Documents\iMacros\Macros\test.iim");
```

How can i keep the proxy connection until iimPlay() finish ? And without copying all individual .iim files inside my .js (the point is to have a "launcher" file that will connect and verify a proxy and then run any macro file)

```
var macro = "CODE:";
macro += "VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
macro += "CLEAR" + "\n";
macro += "SET !FILESTOPWATCH mydata.csv" + "\n";
macro += "STOPWATCH ID=total" + "\n";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\proxies.csv" + "\n";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
macro += "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n";
macro += "SET !VAR9 {{rnd}}" + "\n";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR9}}" + "\n";
macro += "SET !TIMEOUT 30" + "\n";
macro += "PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
macro += "URL GOTO=http://www.alterweb.ca/ip.php?csv=ligne{{!VAR9}}" + "\n";
macro += "WAIT SECONDS=3" + "\n";


var part2 = "CODE:";
part2 += "VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
part2 += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
part2 += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\proxies.csv" + "\n";
part2 += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
part2 += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{line}}" + "\n";
part2 += "PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
part2 += "WAIT SECONDS=6" + "\n";


var big_count=parseFloat(prompt("loops=?",1000));
var fichier=parseFloat(prompt("fichier imacro","C:\\Users\\Libertad\\Documents\\iMacros\\Macros\\test.iim"));


for(var x=0;x<big_count;x++)
{
    var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*2000 + 1);
    iimSet("rnd",rand);
    iimPlay(macro);

    if(window.content.document.body.textContent.contains('proxy'))
    {
        //if proxy word found
        iimSet("line",rand);
        iimPlay(part2);  // at this point the proxy connection is established
        iimPlay("C:\Users\Libertad\Documents\iMacros\Macros\test.iim");

    }   
    else
    {
        //if proxy word isn't found
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

View how this snippet works:

```
var prefs = imns.Pref;
var proxy = "123.456.789.123";
var port = "1234":
prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.http", proxy, true);
prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port", port, true);
```

I hope that you'll find the way to apply it to your script.

Comment: @macroscripts, Certainly!